# Please help me resolve my Ant + Ivy + Java build/dependency issues

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ivy, build-dependencies

I can get Eclipse to export a standalone JAR file which works fine.  But when I try to use my build.xml file with Ant I get about 100 errors because a bunch of references can not be resolved.

Here is my build.xml

```
  <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

      <!-- ================================= 
            target: resolve              
           ================================= -->
      <target name="resolve" description="--> retrieve dependencies with ivy">
          <ivy:retrieve />
      </target>

  <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
  <target name="compile" depends="resolve,clean, makedir">
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
        <src path="${lib.dir}"/>
    </javac>

  </target>

  <!-- Creates Javadoc -->
  <target name="docs" depends="compile">
    <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
      <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
       <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
           </fileset>
    </javadoc>
  </target>

  <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\hcm.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.heromanager.MainWindow" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="main" depends="compile, jar, docs">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>

</project>
```

Here is the ivy.xml file

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.herocombatmanager" module="mainwindow"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.0"/>
        <dependency org="com.jgoodies" name="looks" rev="2.2.2"/>
        <dependency org="com.jgoodies" name="forms" rev="1.2.1"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

And here are a few of the errors :-)

```
[javac] H:\Development\Workspace\HeroCombatManager\src\org\herocombatmanager\XMLParser.java:3: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
[javac]                                ^
[javac] H:\Development\Workspace\HeroCombatManager\src\org\herocombatmanager\AttackAdvantagesPanel.java:10: package com.jgoodies.forms.factories does not exist
[javac] import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.FormFactory;
[javac]                                    ^
[javac] H:\Development\Workspace\HeroCombatManager\src\org\herocombatmanager\AttackAdvantagesPanel.java:11: package com.jgoodies.forms.layout does not exist
[javac] import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.*;
[javac] ^
...
[javac] H:\Development\Workspace\HeroCombatManager\src\org\herocombatmanager\AttackAdvantagesPanel.java:40: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class FormLayout
[javac] location: class org.herocombatmanager.AttackAdvantagesPanel
[javac]         this.setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
[javac]                            ^
[javac] H:\Development\Workspace\HeroCombatManager\src\org\herocombatmanager\AttackAdvantagesPanel.java:40: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class ColumnSpec
[javac] location: class org.herocombatmanager.AttackAdvantagesPanel
[javac]         this.setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
[javac]                                           ^
```

Thank you all in advance..

Comment: Javac needs the lib dir to be in a classmate element not a src element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @oers has pointed out, you cannot add the jar files in the "lib" directory as source files, the [javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task doesn't work that way.

What you need to add the jars resolved by ivy to an ANT classpath. The simplest way to do this is to use the ivy [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task as follows:

```
  <target name="resolve" description="--> retrieve dependencies with ivy">
     <ivy:resolve/>
     <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="resolve,clean, makedir">
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" classpathref="compile.path">
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
    </javac>
  </target>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.  Unfortunately I ran into another problem.

I am getting this error when I do an Ant Build:

"The archive: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_33/lib/tools.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist."

Comment: @David Sounds like the JVM you're using to run ANT is not a JDK (as opposed to a JRE). See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ant]+tools.jar

Comment: Thank you that was what I needed.  Now my problems are all XML formatting types of problems and I can figure those out myself.